# Will looking up a null-able column in oracle 9i suppress the column's index?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

According to Oracle 9i performance tuning tips and techniques, using `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` will suppress the index of the column - if there is an index on the column, and recommends making the column not null-able and using a `DEFAULT`.

The question is, will a null-able column suppress an index even if my select query does not use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a general query, the fact that a column is nullable won't prevent the optimizer or query engine from using an index unless the criterion on the column is `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.  So, a general `WHERE column = somevalue` query will use the index if that is appropriate.

The situation where the (nullable) column is one of several columns in the index is less clear.  In the absence of concrete information to the contrary, I'd assume that the index will be used if there are criteria on the other columns in the index, possibly even with an `IS [NOT] NULL` criterion on the nullable column.  It might depend on whether or not the nullable column is the lead column for the index.

Comment: I remember that in the case of a composite index (or any other terms), prior to 9i, if the lead column of a composite index is not specified in the where clause, then a full table scan would be used, but i did not read the part where it mentioned a IS [NOT] NULL situation..

Comment: If the lead column(s) are not specified (given conditions), then the index provides minimal to no benefit, which is why it is not used.  The answer is quasi-speculative. The first paragraph I'm confident of; the second is less clear cut, and my experience with other DBMS might not apply to Oracle 9i.  If the nullable column were the second column of a three-column index, and equality criteria were specified for the first and third columns but an 'IS NOT NULL' was specified for the second (nullable) column, I'd _expect_ the index to be used, but I do not _know_ that Oracle 9i would use it.